# Compare two fields in different feature classes using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, cursor, proximity

I am trying to make an automation script to evaluate the distance and compare attributes between an incoming layer and another existing layer in the database.

I made this script to say:

> If the reference of the incoming layer is already existing in the
> database then we calculate the distance between these two entities.

Now I want to compare also a field called "CODE_SITE" between the two layers to say :

> If the distance between the entities is > 50 and "CODE_SITE" is the
> same:   then we increment the reference.

I'm having trouble developing the distance and field comparison part.

How do I do it in a simpler way?

```
pattern_poteaux = r"(POT|PHT)+[-]+[0-9]{5}[-]+[a-zA-Z]{2}[-][0-9]*"
pattern_chambre = r"CHB+[-]+[0-9]+[-]+[a-zA-Z]{2}[-]+[0-9]*"

"""
@param :
1: pattern regex
2: string
return Booleen si la référence est valide
"""
def attribute_check(pattern, sample_str):
    if re.search(pattern, sample_str) is not None:
        return True
    else:
        return False

"""
@param: chaine de caractère
return : incrémente la référence de 1 
"""
reference_incrementee = []
reference_invalide = []
def increment_ref(pattern, sample_str):
    if attribute_check(pattern, sample_str) == True:
        reference_incrementee.append(sample_str)
        return re.sub(r'[^-]+[0-9]$', lambda x: str(int(x.group()) + 1).zfill(len(x.group())), sample_str)   
    else:
      reference_invalide.append(sample_str)

AX_CHAMBER = r'\OSP_LOADER.mdb\AX_CHAMBER'
CHAMB = r'\OSP_LOADER.mdb\CHAMBER'
DicorefCh={}
fcc1=['REFERENCE', 'OBJECTID', "SHAPE@XY", "CODE_SITE" ]
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(CHAMB,fcc1) as c:
     for row1 in c:
         DicorefCh[row1[0]]=[row1[1],row1[2], row1[3]]
del c
DicorefCh2={}
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(AX_CHAMBER,fcc2) as cursor:
     for row in cursor:
         DicorefCh2[row[0]]=[row[2], row[12]]
del cursor 
fcc2=["REFERENCE", "EXIST", "INTER", "RESUL", "OBJECTID", "SHAPE@XY","CODE_SITE"]
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(AX_CHAMBER,fcc2) as cursor:
     for row in cursor:
         row[2]=0
         cursor.updateRow(row)
         score=int(row[1])+int(row[2])
         if (score==1) and row[4] in doubref:
             idND=DicorefCh[DicorefCh2[row[4]]]
             d=math.sqrt((idND[1][0]-row[5][0])**2+(idND[1][1]-row[5][1])**2)
             ax_code_site = row[7]
             ref_ax_chambre = row[0]
         if d > 50.0 :
               increment_ref(pattern_chambre, ref_ax_chambre)
```

[image: AX_CHAMBER]

[image: CHAMBER]

Comment: I edited the question with the screenshot, i have 50000  features in each table

Comment: Where is `increment_ref()` defined?

Comment: Why is the `updateRow()` call before all the code doing the comparison?

Comment: because i init the score of row[2] to 0. INTER. the function i defined it in another file i will put the function now